node (express) application error related to not finding cors even after installing it
I'm building a express application and after installing cors, the build fails saying that cors is not installed. I have removed node_modules several times, prune the cache (I use pnpm) and so on at not avail. I have install cors with the --save option but nothing
This is the relevant code in the app

This is the dependencies on my package.json

And this is the error:

I'm really lost. Any help will be greatly appreciate it.

I often had such problems with npm and after I switched to yarn I got rid of this, I suggest you consider this.
